# Find the location of a hidden host

Tags: ssh, known-vulnerabilities, reconnaissance

I'm doing a penetration test for a client who wants me to try and target a specific server. I have managed to get credentials(hard-coded in an in-house app) to a limited account on this server that works with sftp, but won't give a shell with SSH.

The message states that shells are only available when connecting from the opsware jumpbox.

I've tried looking at known_hosts, hosts, whatever config files I have permission to grab, and searching all through the DNS. I can't find a reference to it anywhere.

What are some other tips I could use to get the host of the "opsware jumpbox"?

Comment: What permissions does the limited account have? In particular, can you upload files? Where?

Comment: @Gilles I have write access to the users home directory and /tmp via sftp. I can't execute anything or set anything to execute. I can't get a shell of any sort except via a specific host, that I can't find via DNS or hosts files.

Comment: Could you add a .crontab file in the home directory?  It may give you a possibility to execute something.  Or, see if there's anything useful in .bash_history, ...

Comment: Closing because the question is essentially "how do I find a box I know nothing about or where it is?" Keep gathering info.